# Python BeautifulSoup Web Scrape Inside a Div Tag

Tags: web-scraping, python-3.6

I'm banging my head into a wall over this. I've successfully parsed out most of the tables on this page with no problem, but the `<div>` tag one has confounded me.

Page = `https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/TBL/2018.html`

this:

```
table_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table_wrapper setup_long long 
setup_commented commented', 'id': 'all_stats_adv_rs'})
```

gets me the div tag I am looking for, and I assumed I could just pull out the table:

```
using table_body = table_div.find('tbody')
```

but that returns nothing, and I really don't know why. If I do a simple:

```
for row in table_div:
        if 'tbody' in row:
            print ("Found")
```

I get "found", so it's clearly there, so why can't .find find that text?

The above process has worked for every other table, why not this one? I've even tried looking for TRs ... it's like `table_div` isn't what find is expecting to work on.

I hate asking for help, but I'm really at a loss on this one. Help me see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

The table you're looking for is placed inside an html comment `<!-- -->`. A [`Comment`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings) object is a type of `NavigableString`,  so you can't use `.find` or any other `Tag` methods.

However, you can select the comment and build a new `BeautifulSoup` object from it.

```
from bs4 import Comment

table_div = soup.find('div', {'class':'table_wrapper', 'id':'all_stats_adv_rs'})
comment = table_div.find(string=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')

print(soup2.find('tbody'))
```

Comment: I logged back in to say I figured it out! Not as well as you, but yeah, it's in a danged comment! The way I "fixed" it was to cycle through the file as a list of rows and just delete all the comment tags ('<!--' not the whole row. But I'm going to try implementing your method. Thank you SO much for your input and help at making me a better coder!